# Why do I get an "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error message?

Tags: amsmath, multline

What's wrong with the following equation?

```
\begin{multline}
D^n(uv)=uD^nv+\frac{n}{n!}DuD^{n-1}v+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}D^2uD^{n-2}v+\ldots \
&+\frac{n(n-1)\ldots (n-m+1)}{m!}D^muD^{n-m}v+\ldots + D^nuv,
\end{multline}
```

Error message:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E. Please edit your post : put four spaces at the beginning of your lines of codes and make your MWE fully compiliable, with a valid preamble of anything needed to compile. We should be able to compile with a simple copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- change the single backslash, `\`, at the end of the first row to a double backslash, `\\`; and
- drop the `&` character at the start of the second row.

Additionally, I would use `\cdots` instead of `\ldots` throughout. Bonus typographic touch: insert a thinspace between `D^nu` and `v` in the final summand; that, or write `(D^n u)v`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
D^n(uv)=uD^nv+\frac{n}{n!}DuD^{n-1}v+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}D^2uD^{n-2}v+\cdots \\
+\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-m+1)}{m!}D^muD^{n-m}v+\cdots + D^nu\,v,
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using TeXnicCenter and it works!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your code!
\begin{multline}
D^n(uv)=uD^nv+\frac{n}{n!}DuD^{n-1}v+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}D^2uD^{n-2}v+\ldots \\
+\frac{n(n-1)\ldots (n-m+1)}{m!}D^muD^{n-m}v+\ldots + D^nuv
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP `multline` has a `,` at the end. Don't know if it changes anything (I don't use math syntax), but it may be worth putting it in your answer.

Comment: @sztruks: The comma is intentionally removed to save more space. Please reattach if the OP wants.

Comment: The equation works for me too but it still shows an error! Any error automatically will fail my work.

Comment: Since the OP's issues are entirely unrelated to TeXnicCenter, I wouldn't refer to it.